# how to create dynamic links between two cells of 2 html tables in html email using java

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail, html-table

One of our customers has got a requirement to create a html based email with html table for each automation script as part of test automation framework.

The Second requirement is to have one more html table constructed for quick view purpose. the table cells in the first column should contain hyperlink to the table header of each html table generated per each automated script, meaning the the cell-1 in the column-1 of the table-2 should point to the table header of the table-1 of automated script-1 .

I was stuck as how to create links dynamically between a cell and corresponding table header.

So I wanted to seek suggestions and advice from gurus and seniors and that will indeed be an immense help.

Comment: My immediate thinking is HTML anchor links, but I don't know how email clients react to those.

Comment: thanks a lot will try what you suggested

Comment: sorry to get back, i am still not able to solve it. any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check out link [html # anchors](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp), this explain how you can use id attribute and # href to create links for elements within same or different html pages. Lookout for section **HTML Links - The id Attribute**

Comment: Thanks a lot Sagar, will try your suggestion

Comment: sorry to get back, i am still not able to solve it. any help will be greatly appreciated